# Toggle text on pressing the button in react native

Tags: toggle

I am new to react native and I want to toggle text on pressing the button, but the problem is that when I press button the text changed but when I press it again nothing happen. Here is my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsZfv.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the function on:

```
const [tooggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

    function textChange() {
        setToggle(!tooggle);
        return isTrue === tooggle
            ? setOutputText('first')
            : setOutputText('second');
    }
```

Example of toggle:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const ToggleFunction = () => {
    const [outPutText, setOutputText] = useState('first');
    const [tooggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

    function textChange() {
        setToggle(!tooggle);
        return tooggle ? setOutputText('first') : setOutputText('second');
    }
    return (
        <View
            style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}
        >
            <Text>{outPutText}</Text>
            <Button title="button" onPress={textChange} />
        </View>
    );
};

export { ToggleFunction };
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use react hooks, you configure the component to do things after it renders. If you declare a variable outside of a `useState` hook, it will be reset on every render. This is what happens to your `isTrue` variable. Read more about the rules of hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions).

You also don't need to evaluate `isTrue == true`, you can just call `isTrue`, it will have the same effect.

```
export default function App() {
    var startingText = "First text"
    const [isTrue, setIsTrue] = useState(true)
    const [outputText, setOutputText] = useState(startingText)


    function textChange() {
        setIsTrue(!isTrue)
        return isTrue ? startingText : setOutputText("Text Changed")
    }

    return(
       <View>
           <Text>{outputText}</Text>
           <Button title="Change Text" onPress={textChange}/>
       </View>
    )
}
```

You can simplify the code even further by removing the boolean variable and moving the logic of selecting which text value to set in the `textChange` function directly using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```
 export default function App() {
    var startingText = ""
    const [outputText, setOutputText] = useState(startingText)


    function textChange() {
        setOutputText(outputText === startingText ? "Text Changed" : startingText)
    }

    return(
       <View>
           <Text>{outputText}</Text>
           <Button title="Change Text" onPress={textChange}/>
       </View>
    )
}
```